# how to setvisible(true) a JFrame which i had setvisible(false) when loading other jframe class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

//I have 2 JFrame classes say login and homepage

what i did in login() is:

```
   class login extends JFrame{
      homepage hp= new homepage();
      setVisible(false);
      hp.setVisible(true);
   }
```

but now if i want to load login JFrame i have to write:

```
class homepage extends JFrame{
   new login().setVisible();
}
```

but my query is that above line creates a new object of login class but previous jframe object of login is hidden. how do i set that object to visible without creating new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you should save some link to your login frame object. For example, you can make your login frame class as singletone and get the same instance when you need, or just pass login frame link to your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Make your object a instace object so u could access it from the constructor

Answer (score 0):

you can code like this using a custom constructor

```
       class login extends JFrame{
          homepage hp= new homepage(this);
          setVisible(false);
          hp.setVisible(true);
       }

class homepage extends JFrame{

    private login loginObj;

    public homepage(login loginObj){
    this.loginObj=loginObj;
    loginObj.setVisible(true);
    }

    }
```